# Why do you need reputation to post on meta?

Tags: support, meta, reputation

While this website is in the embryonic stage being able to post meta threads important.

could you move this thread to meta rather than closing it?

Comment: This is clearly addressed in the FAQ.

Comment: and it's not math- (or meta-math-) related either :-)

Comment: See the FAQ on the meta site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @muad, yeah, it's really frustrating. But think about it, it might be frustrating to see such a question when you were looking for a math related question. I hope the moderator will give you a bonus reputation to post on meta. Why won't you send them an email asking that?

Comment: @Elazar: 5 reputation isn't that hard to get. Even this question managed to get muad up that high.

Comment: Indeed, if you start asking a question, side notice says "If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.", but you need a question (on this site) voted up in order to write a question on meta. Maybe a different method of getting a bit of reputation (say, compiling all user profile fields) could be a nice idea.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have minimum reputation on SOFU sites, than you automatically have 100 reputation.

That removes the barrier to post on meta.